# TimeZone conversion issue in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I want to insert date in Central Timezone as creation_date. I changed the jvm timezone(US/Central) and created date with timezone(Timezone) and able to insert into DB in case of **local** master url but when master url changed to **YARN** its not working properly. It inserting time with 2 hours lesser then Central Timezone. I even tested with changing **Spark Session** timezone but same result its updating 2 hours lesser time in DB

```
 //sparksession timezone change
 session.conf().set("spark.sql.session.timezone","US/Central");

TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Dataset<Row> mydata= dataset1.withColumn("Creation_date" , function.lit(time).cast("timestamp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using System Time API and changing the System time zone, use java 8 APIs to generate the current time in the required timezone. `LocalDateTime` can be directly converted to `java.sql.Timestamp`

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

Timestamp time= Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("US/Central")));
Dataset<Row> mydata= dataset1.withColumn("Creation_date" , lit(time));
```

Comment: Its not about only conversion of timestamp , Its about while saving in DB and when master URL is As YARN.

Answer (score 0):

After adding two extra configuration in Sparksession its worked fine for me.

> NOTE: I was facing time difference issue in DB when I was using master as Yarn but it was working fine

```
SparkSession session=SparkSession.builder()
.appName("somename")
.master("yarn")
.config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=US/Central") 
.config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Duser.timezone=US/Central") 
.getOrCreate();

session.conf().set("spark.sql.session.timezone","US/Central");

TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
Timestamp time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Dataset<Row> mydata= dataset1.withColumn("Creation_date" , function.lit(time).cast("timestamp"))
```